# How to fix :Trying to get property of non-object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to resolve this problem ?

```
if (strpos($scripts->item($i)->nodeValue, "test") !== false) { //line 127
    return true       
}
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 127

Comment: The error is telling you that `$scripts->item($i)` is not an object. There is not enough information here to help us tell you why, but I suspect there aren't `$i` items in `$scripts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if values exist at all

```
if(!empty($scripts->item($i)->nodeValue))
{
//your code
}
```